# What actually gets modified upon modifying an object whose reference is been already created in the following code?

Tags: php, class, object, reference

I'm using **PHP 7.1.11**

Consider below code :

```
<?php
  class SimpleClass {
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
      echo $this->var;
    }
  }

  $instance = new SimpleClass();

  $assigned   =  $instance;
  $reference  =& $instance;

  $instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';

  $instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null

  var_dump($instance);
  var_dump($reference);
  var_dump($assigned);
?>
```

The output of above program is as below :

```
NULL
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
   ["var"]=>
     string(30) "$assigned will have this value"
}
```

If you look at the code line `$reference  =& $instance;` you can notice that a reference to the existing class object(`& instance`) is created and assigned to the variables `$reference`.

Then my question is related to the below code lines :

```
$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';

$instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null
```

What these statements are actually modifying the original object or the data present at the reference of an object?

I expected the output of the statement `var_dump($assigned);` as `NULL` but it's not. Why so? What's the reason behind this? How the PHP program flow is working here?

Why upon execution of the statement `$instance = null;` the variable `$assigned` is not getting assigned to the value `NULL`?

Comment: Regarding *Why upon execution of the statement $instance = null; the variable $assigned is not getting assigned to the value NULL?*: See [PHP: Unsetting References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php)

Comment: Why are you even doing any of this?! Stop defining your variables as public and stop assigning object by reference! Also, get a damned book.

Comment: @tereško : This is an example from the PHP manual and I'm having hard time in understanding it. So, I'm asking for help. I want to make my concepts crystal clear.

Comment: @user2839497 the concept that you are asking about is bullshit. You should not pass objects by reference. Ever. It is a leftover from PHP 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to realize with this is that the different variables hold the object identifier, not the object itself. From [the PHP documentation for Objects and References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

So, step by step:

1. First the object is created, and the object identifier is assigned to `$instance`.

   ```
   $instance = new SimpleClass();
   ```
2. a copy of the object identifier is assigned to `$assigned`.

   ```
   $assigned = $instance;
   ```
3. a reference to the object identifier is assigned to `$reference`.

   ```
   $reference  =& $instance;
   ```
4. obviously, this modifies the `var` property of the object that all the different variables refer to.

   ```
   $instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';
   ```
5. This statement replaces the object identifier in `$instance` with `null`, and by reference, it's also replaced in `$reference`.

   ```
   $instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null
   ```

But after setting `$instance` to null, the object itself still exists, and `$assigned` still holds a copy of its identifier.

---

Here's an MSPaint visual aid in case, since I've been told I can be somewhat obtuse. (I left out step 4.)

[image]

Comment: As per PHP manual "When assigning an already created instance of a class to a new variable, the new variable will access the same instance as the object that was assigned". Then, after execution of the code $assigned = $instance; Both $assigned and $instance will point to the same value and any changes made to this value should get reflected in both $assigned and $instance. You are saying exactly opposite. You are saying that after execution of the code $assigned = $instance; a copy of the object identifier is assigned to $assigned. As per manual both variables should access the same value.

Comment: I don't think I'm saying the opposite. The manual states that the new variable will access the same instance, and `$assigned` and `$instance` _do_ access exactly the same instance of the class; they just access it through different identifiers. I think the manual is just trying to emphasize that the instance is not copied when it's assigned to a new variable.

Comment: That's what I'm also saying " that the instance is not copied when it's assigned to a new variable". But you are saying the copy of object identifier is created. Are the statements $assigned = $instance; and $assigned = & $instance; do the same thing?

Comment: They do almost the same thing, but with an important difference. Unless you reassign `$instance` as you've done in your example, you won't be able to tell the difference. But since assigning by reference points the new variable to the same object identifier rather than copying it, setting the original variable to `null` or something else will affect the other variable if it was assigned by reference, but won't affect it if it was assigned by value.

Comment: @ Don't Panic : Today I understood the whole concept clearly. Such a wonderfully easy to understand explanation in short and sweet way you have given. Just couple of request I want to make you. Please explain what does mean by object accessors and in the text from manual? What's its role in above code? Please, please, please add step 4 to the MSPaint visual, so the answer will get entirely complete and 100% full-proof. Thanks once again buddy for such a wonderful answer. Please consider my requests and update the answer accordingly.